# C# WPF Datagrid in Tab Control (dynamically created) not showing Data

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I try to create a dynamically created TabControl with integrated Datagrid for each created Tab.
Why dynamic created Tabs? The User can open multiple Files, and the amount of selected files are the amount of tabs. 
Why Datagrid inside the Tabs. Each Tab contains (in the future) a huge number of calculated data, which should be shown in the Datagrid.

This approach shows the Datagrid in every Tab and also shows the Column "Name", but no Data is shown beneath it.

XAML:

```
<TabControl x:Name="TabControlCells" Margin="10,291,635,0"  Height="229" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <DataGrid x:Name="DataGridCells" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Files}" >
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="True" />

                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>

            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

C#:

```
private void Calculate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    void ThreadCompletion() {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
            TabControlCells.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            foreach (File file in Globals.Files) {
                TabItem item = new TabItem {
                    Header = file.FileName.Split('.')[0]
                };
                item.Content = file.Cells;
                TabControlCells.Items.Add(item);
            }
            TabControlCells.SelectedIndex = 0;
        });
    }

    Thread Calculations = new Thread(() => 
    {
        try 
        {
            Mean.CalculateBaselineMean();
        }
        finally 
        {
            ThreadCompletion();
        }
    });
    Calculations.Start();
}
```

File Class:

```
private readonly int _id;
private string _path;
private string _filename;
private double _limit;
private bool _high_stimulus_output;
private bool _normalized_data_output;
private List<Cell> _cells;
private int _cellCount;
private int _rowCount;
private double _minutes;
private string[] _content;

public File(int ID, string Path, string FileName, double Limit,bool High_Stimulus_Output, bool Normalized_Data_Ouput, List<Cell> Cells, int CellCount, int RowCount, double Minutes, string[] Content)
{
    _id = ID;
    _filename = FileName;
    _path = Path;
    _limit = Limit;
    _high_stimulus_output = High_Stimulus_Output;
    _normalized_data_output = Normalized_Data_Ouput;
    _cells = Cells;
    _cellCount = CellCount;
    _rowCount = RowCount;
    _minutes = Minutes;
    _content = Content;
}

public string FileName { get => _filename; set => _filename = value; }
public int ID { get => _id;}
public string Path { get => _path; set => _path = value; }
public double Limit { get => _limit; set => _limit = value; }
public bool High_Stimulus_Output { get => _high_stimulus_output; set => _high_stimulus_output = value; }
public bool Normalized_data_output { get => _normalized_data_output; set => _normalized_data_output = value; }
public int CellCount { get => _cellCount; set => _cellCount = value; }
public int RowCount { get => _rowCount; set => _rowCount = value; }
public double Minutes { get => _minutes; set => _minutes = value; }
public string[] Content { get => _content; set => _content = value; }
internal List<Cell> Cells { get => _cells; set => _cells = value; }
```

Cell Class:

```
class Cell 
{
    private string _name;
    private List<TimeFrame> _time_frames;
    private double _baseline_mean;
    private double _all_mean;
    private List<TimeFrame> _normalized_time_frames;
    private double _maximum;
    private double _over_under_limit;
    private int _high_stimulus_per_minute;

    public Cell(string Name, List<TimeFrame> Timeframes, double Baseline_Mean, double All_Mean, List<TimeFrame> Normalized_Timeframes, double Maximum, double Over_Under_Limit, int High_Stimulus_Per_Minute) {
        _name = Name;
        _time_frames = Timeframes;
        _baseline_mean = Baseline_Mean;
        _all_mean = All_Mean;
        _normalized_time_frames = Normalized_Timeframes;
        _maximum = Maximum;
        _over_under_limit = Over_Under_Limit;
        _high_stimulus_per_minute = High_Stimulus_Per_Minute;
    }

    public string Name { get => _name; set => _name = value; }
    public List<TimeFrame> Timeframes { get => _time_frames; set => _time_frames = value; }
    public double Baseline_Mean { get => _baseline_mean; set => _baseline_mean = value; }
    public double All_mean { get => _all_mean; set => _all_mean = value; }
    public List<TimeFrame> Normalized_Timeframes { get => _normalized_time_frames; set => _normalized_time_frames = value; }
    public double Maximum { get => _maximum; set => _maximum = value; }
    public double Over_under_limit { get => _over_under_limit; set => _over_under_limit = value; }
    public int High_stimulus_per_minute { get => _high_stimulus_per_minute; set => _high_stimulus_per_minute = value; }
}
```

TimeFrame Class:

```
class TimeFrame 
{
    private readonly int _id;
    private readonly double _value;
    private readonly int _including_minute;

    public TimeFrame(int ID, double Value, int Including_Minute) {
        _id = ID;
        _value = Value;
        _including_minute = Including_Minute;
    }

    public int ID { get => _id; }
    public double Value { get => _value; }
    public int Minute { get => _including_minute; }
}
```

I searched for hours and tried several solutions found on github, but no success. 
I think there is something wrong with the Bindings? Or is there something else i hardly missed?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Actual State]

Comment: Have you implemented the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface?  It notifies the view when something in the logic has changed.

Comment: No, where should i put this ? But i should specify, the Datagrid shows the header "name", but no Data is shown.

Comment: [link](https://docs.telerik.com/data-access/deprecated/developers-guide/code-generation/developer-guide-code-generation-implement-inotifypropertychanged) this website gives a good example of how to implement it.

Comment: @Exitare You haven't set the Sources, so you don't have any tab items.

Comment: @M312V if i load two files i get two tabs, with Datagrid header columns but no data. I attached a photo in my origin post.

Comment: @Exitare: You are binding the `DataGrid` to a property named `Files`. Where is this property defined? In your `Calculate` method you seem to create a `TabItem` per `File` in `Global.Files`. This doesn't make much sense to me. Please clarify your issue.

Comment: @mm8 the List “files” is created dynamically when the user selects text files from an open file Dialog. For example: user selects two files -> two file objects will be created. the property named files is wrong. The correct source I want to use , is the List<Cell>, which is a „file“ member.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious reason is that you haven’t set a DataContext for the TabControl. With data binding, you don’t dynamically create TabItems and add them to the TabControl, you just set a DataContext and the TabItems as well as the DataGrid in each TabItem is populated for you.

So instead of

```
foreach (File file in Globals.Files) {
                TabItem item = new TabItem {
                    Header = file.FileName.Split('.')[0]
                };


                item.Content = file.Cells;
                TabControlCells.Items.Add(item);


            }
```

You just specify its

```
TabControlCells.ItemsSource = Globals.Files;
```

Comment: I added this line:   item.DataContext = file.Cells;
But still nothing happens

Comment: Sadly, the column header is shown, but again no data  is shown. :/. Also i guess its the wrong list, i want to populate the grids with the Cell List not the File List

Comment: There are errors in your binding expression. While debugging, check the output window and fix those errors. In order for the DataGrid to bind to the Cells, you need to write a binding for the DataGrid, too, in the XAML code.

Comment: Yeah you´re right. There are errors like this:
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'File' property not found on 'object' ''File' (HashCode=42526340)'. BindingExpression:Path=File; DataItem='File' (HashCode=42526340); target element is 'DataGrid' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')